Cedar Board & Batten Siding Repair - Advice Needed
I have a MCM home built in 1974 with old cedar board and batten siding. I am getting ready to reside the exterior.
The area is about 10' x 12'. The original builders used alternating 5" and 7" tongue and groove cedar boards over some type of black felt fiberboard sheathing. I am planning to finish with LP Smartside cedar look paneling and add in batten strips to match the existing look.
My planned system is as follows:
stud - exterior grade plywood sheathing - house wrap - flashing 
  - LP Smartside - batten strips - primer & paint

Am I forgetting or leaving out any large steps in the process? Anything I should know heading into this project? I have multiple years of flooring experience and some deckbuilding under my belt but have never approached a siding project before.

What is an "MCM home"? I removed some irrelevant back-story. Please take the [tour]. We like to stick to the relevant facts here.

You have the right idea, but that's all rather vague. To be sure we'd need to see the details of what you're flashing, for example. Consider adding photos to your post.

Your location (i.e. climate) and exterior wall construction details (i.e. thickness, insulation, roof overhang, etc.) would be highly relevant.

MCM- Mid century modern.  I can add photos later.  Location is Midwest (Missouri), we get some pretty good storms.  the cedar paneling looked to be ~3/4" and the sheathing probably 1/2" no overhang.  insulation looks to be old school r13 roll
